# How to resolve a server path on Windows with Pathlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

So I have a path to a server that looks like

```
\\foo\bar\baz
```

I am trying to convert this to a Path object with Python's pathlib library with something like

```
Path('\\foo').joinpath('bar').joinpath('baz')
```

Trying to see if this path exists with "path.exists()" however signals that the path doesn't exist.

I have also replace the starting path of the path with the following the same result:

```
Path(r'\\foo'), Path('\\\\foo'), Path('\foo)
```

Printing out the path after being parsed by Path appears to show the path being interpreted as, no matter how the foo root is entered

```
'C:/foo/bar/baz'
```

However when I simply plop the path in os.path.exists as a raw string, the path is successfully found (using a normal string results in a unicode error)

```
os.path.exists(r'\\foo\bar\baz')
```

Is there anyway to use Pathlib in such a way that the server path is successfully parsed / interpreted, or am I forced to just use a raw string with os.path operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r'\\foo'` is just not a valid windows UNC path, even if `foo` exists. You need at least a sharename after that.

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dfsc/149a3039-98ce-491a-9268-2f5ddef08192):

> A valid UNC path MUST contain two or more path components.

This creates a valid path object on which `exists()` will work properly:

```
>>> pathlib.Path(r'\\foo\bar').joinpath('baz')
WindowsPath('//foo/bar/baz')
```